# Sorting with a certain condition using decorator - python

Tags: python, sorting, decorator, python-decorators

There are names, score, and class in the list like this

```
students = [['Paul', 90, 'a'], ['Michael', 50, 'b'],['Gina', 90, 'c'],['Marie', 70, 'b']]
```

and each class has slogan:

```
a   Good A 
b   Great B 
c   Best C
```

The list should be sorted by higher score and printed name and slogan based on the sorted order.(In case 2 or more ppl have the same score, print from higher index)

Thus, the output according to the list above should be:

```
Best C: Gina
Good A: Paul
Great B: Marie
Great B: Michael
```

At first, I tried with 2 functions, one is to sort the list and the other one is to print the output, and it worked fine.

Then I wanted to add decorator on it, but as I'm not used to use decorator, I barely finished coding like this.

```
def do_sort(students):
    def takeSecond(elem):
      return elem[1]
    students.sort(key=takeSecond)
    sorted_students = []
    for student in students:
      sorted_students.append(student)

    return sorted_students
 
def get_list(func):
    def decorated(students):
      a = 'Good A'
      b = 'Great B' 
      c = 'Best C'
      do_sort(students)
      newlist = []
      for student in students:
        if student[2] == 'a':
          student[2] = a
        elif student[2] == 'b':
          student[2] = b
        elif student[2] == 'c':
          student[2] = c
        newlist.append('{}:{}'.format(student[2], student[0]))
        # del newlist[0]
        result = []
        result.append(newlist[::-1])
      for each in result:
        return result.pop()
    return decorated
 
@get_list
def print_output(each_student):
     output = each_student
     return output
 
students = [['Paul', 90, 'a'], ['Michael', 50, 'b'],['Gina', 90, 'c'],['Marie', 70, 'b']]
print(*print_output(students), sep='\n')
```

Though it gives a correct result, it seems like function print_output (which is decorated by get_list) is not really needed for I did pretty much every thing in get_list function.

I wonder if it's a right way of using decorator.
if it isn't, I'd like to know a better way of doing it because I'm now kind of stuck in the concept. Any corrections on the codes are appreciated.

Comment: The point of writing a decorator is that you can use it to decorate multiple functions. If it's just for this one use, there's no need for it.

Comment: yeah I know. The reason why I asked this question is to understand the concept, so it's not only related to this one use. Thanks for the comment!